# Slurm queue only one specific software per job

Tags: queue, slurm, sbatch, workload

I'm using a slurm queue system and I wanted to be able to queue a list of jobs. The problem I have is that the software I am using it can only be used once at the time. So if a job is using it, the next in queue has to finish until the previous is over.
maybe a queue that can only run one job at the time?
thanks for any help you can give me!

I tried to use
--dependency=afterok:$jobid
but for that I need to always check the jobid of the previous job and I though it should be a way to configure slurm to do this automatically

Answer (score 1):

This is the typical use case for [licenses](https://slurm.schedmd.com/licenses.html) in Slurm. The idea is to define a number of licences available for that software (here, only 1) and then use the `--licence` option for jobs that require that software. Slurm will then only schedule such job when a licence is available.

**If you are not administrator** and cannot change the Slurm configuration, a workaround is to give all your jobs the same name (`--job-name`) and use `--dependency=singleton`. That will instruct Slurm to one run one of such job at a time.